# Linear algebra constructions on vector bundles

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-bundles

There's a meta-theorem hanging around in the theory of vector bundles that *"Any canonical construction in linear algebra gives rise to a geometric version for holomorphic vector bundles."* (quote from Huybrecht's *Complex Geometry*)

In textbooks, this usually done hands on case-by-case.
I'm looking for a broader view.

1. Which functors $\text{Vect}\to \text{Vect}$ extend to functors in the category of vector bundles over $X$?

Here, an extension of a functor $F:\text{Vect}\to \text{Vect}$ is a functor $\bar F$ between vector bundles such that if $V$ is the typical fiber of $E$ then $F(V)$ is the typical fiber of $F(E)$.

**A partial answer:** a functor $\text{Vect}\to \text{Vect}$ is **smooth** if for every $V$ the induced map $F:GL(V)\to GL(FV)$ is smooth.
In this case, given cocycles $\psi_{ij}$ defining a bundle, the following cocycles defines an extension of $F$:
$$
U_i\cap U_j\xrightarrow{\psi_{ij}} GL(V)\xrightarrow{F} GL(FV)
$$

I believe the most common linear algebra constructions on bundles, such as tensors, sums and exterior powers, come from smooth functors.

2. Are there non-smooth functors $\text{Vect}\to \text{Vect}$ that extend to vector bundles in the above sense? Can we characterize them?
3. Shifting the categorical perspective, does regarding vector bundle as a locally free sheaves brings any insight here? Can these concepts be carried on to algebraic geometry?

Comment: Milnor-Stasheff Characteristic classes Section 3f mentions a sufficient condition:  a functor $F:Vect^k\rightarrow Vect$ gives rise to a vector bundle construction if the functor is *continuous* in the sense that for linear isomorphisms $f_1:V_1\rightarrow W_1,...,f_k:V_k\rightarrow W_k$, $T(f_1,..., f_k)$ depends continuously on the $f_i$ (using the natural topologies on Hom sets of vector spaces, noting that these are finite dimensional vector spaces.)

Comment: This MO post  : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268836/is-the-theory-of-vector-bundles-just-linear-algebra-done-in-a-suitable-topos, is relevant to your question, particularly for the 3. Subquestion !